# What/How to deliver the error for an AMP page if the content is not available

Tags: amp-html

While generating the AMP version of the page, It may happen that the content has been deleted recently and the traffic is still coming.
What would be the correct way do deliver the error page?
Should it be as well in AMP format or a normal 404(non-AMP) page would be enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal 404 should be enough since you don't want the CDN to start serving your 404 page.